# Python Tkinter: Can't manage to refresh window for browsing calendar

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, refresh

I am writing a simple script that is based on a calendar. The core is basically a calendar in which every day of the month is a button and I can access and edit the information stored in it by clicking the day.

So far, the month of the year that is displayed when launching the script is either pre-set by me on the code, or the current month and year is taken from datetime. However, I cannot manage to make the two buttons for browsing months to work.

My logic has been to write the GUI as a "Generic" class, with all the buttons I need, and then the program itself "Application" as another class that inherits from "Generic". The widgets for browsing month I have put in "Application", and not in generic. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

kalender =  tk.Tk()

year = 2017
month = 6
monthmatrix = calendar.monthcalendar(year,month)

class Generic (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.createwidgets()

    def CreateDictKey(self, i, j):
        <Various functions related to what the program needs to do each day>
    def createwidgets(self):
        <All the buttons and widgets that I need on my GUI>

class Application (Generic):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.createwidgets()
        self.previousmonth = tk.Button(self, font=("Helvetica", 15), text= "<", command=lambda: self.PrevMonth()).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NWNESWSE")
        self.nextmonth = tk.Button(self, font=("Helvetica", 15), text= ">", command=lambda: self.NextMonth()).grid(row=0, column=7, sticky="NWNESWSE")

    def PrevMonth(self):
        self.month = month
        self.month = self.month-1
        self.frame.destroy()
        self.createwidgets()

    def NextMonth(self):
        self.month = month
        self.month = self.month+1
        self.frame.destroy()
        self.createwidgets()

app = Application(kalender).grid()
kalender.mainloop()
```

As you can see, my logic so far has been to destroy the window, shift the month by one forwards or backwards, and then call up all the widgets again, i.e. that the calendar configures itself in the new month.

This approach doesn't fully work. It indeed seems to refresh. But pops up in the same month as before though.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mosegui\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/mosegui/Desktop/Calendar/calendar.py", line 173, in <lambda>
    self.nextmonth = tk.Button(self, font=("Helvetica", 15), text= ">", command=lambda: self.NextMonth()).grid(row=0, column=7, sticky="NWNESWSE")
  File "C:/Users/mosegui/Desktop/Calendar/calendar.py", line 187, in NextMonth
    self.frame.destroy()
AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'frame'
```

All help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

D.

Comment: My preferred approach is to disrupt the GUI as little as possible once created. To that end, I would use a table widget containing (at least) 5 rows and 7 columns to represent a typical month. The table widget supports scrolling itself as well as creating widgets within each cell. You could even make each day a button that opens a dialog of events to manage for that day (perhaps functions that read a database based on the date and then display saved events, etc). I would never destroy the table, but merely change the cell contents (move the buttons around).

Comment: Hey Ron. Thanks for your help. But that is not the problem. The calender works just fine, retrieve the info I have on each day etc. The Problem is that it visually strays on the month on which I launch te application. When hitting the month browsing buttons, internally the related information (weekday positions of days, position at the calender table, etc.) functions properly. It just doesn't want to display it on the GUI. I think the problem has to do with the destroy function

Comment: The exception you're getting points to the fact that self.frame variable (not the widget) does not exist in the Application class. Destroying the frame using self.frame.destroy() will destroy the frame and all of its children IF self.frame exists. So the destroy() command itself is not the cause for the exception. Rather it is on creating the frame (not shown in your example).